# Make RecyclerView items into a grid - Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-xml

**What I have**

I currently have a `RecyclerView` that loads a bunch of images and the results look like this,

[image: Normal RecyclerView]

**What I want**

However, I want the images to stack in the `RecyclerView` like this,

[image: Grid RecyclerView]

**Current Code**

This is my current `RecyclerView` item layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:src="@drawable/art"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And this is my adpater for the `RecyclerView`

```
public class ImageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<String> images;
    private AdapterCallback mAdapterCallback;

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView image;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
        }
    }

    public ImageAdapter(ArrayList<String> images, Context context) {
        this.images = images;
        try {
            this.mAdapterCallback = ((AdapterCallback) context);
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException("Activity must implement AdapterCallback.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.image, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final String imageText = images.get(position);
        holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.art);
        holder.image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try {
                    mAdapterCallback.imageSelected(imageText);
                } catch (ClassCastException exception) {
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return images.size();
    }

    public static interface AdapterCallback {
        void imageSelected(String imageText);
    }
}
```

Initializing `RecyclerView`

```
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) imagesDialog.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
ImageAdapter mAdapter = new ImageAdapter(images, this);
recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

How can I achieve the desired effect?

Comment: You need a `GridLayoutManager`.

Comment: It would be useful to see how you declared and setup the RecyclerView. Screenshots and the adapter are nice additions, though

Comment: @cricket_007 I added the initialization of the `RecyclerView` and @EpicPandaForce I am guessing you are referring to where I user `RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());`? I should be using `GridLayoutManger`?

Comment: Just changed this, `RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());` to `RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(CreateActivity.this, 3);` and works like a charm. Thanks @EpicPandaForce

Comment: There are several different layout types you can use, by the way. https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-the-recyclerview#layouts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, on your recyclerView initiation, you should be using GridLayoutManager as the recyclerView's LayoutManager.

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, 3));
```

The '3' in the gridLayoutManager's constructor is the number of items you will have in a row.